# VSCode shortcuts "shift + cmd + [" don't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using an M1 Mac.

I have assigned "View: Open Previous Editor" to the VSCode shortcut "shift + cmd + [", but it does not work.
However, "Open Next Editor" which is assigned to "shift + cmd + ]" works.

When I use "Open Keyboard Shortcuts" and type in "Recording Keys", the combination of "cmd+[" does not work.

It is possible to move to the previous tab by typing "shift + cmd + [" in Google Chrome, so it is unlikely that another shortcut key is overriding it.

Comment: Same issue but no resolution: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114075

Comment: Thank you! I will wait that of resolved.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS + Japanese User + US Keyboard may meet with this issue.

According to following article,
https://aotamasaki.hatenablog.com/entry/command_with_open_bracket_is_unavailable

Goto Preference -> keyboard -> shortcut -> keyboard -> checked off or change settings of 「次のウィンドウを操作対象にする(default setting is cmd+@)」 -> reboot your system
will solve the issue.